# Receiving Invalid Grant Type Error Received From AWS Cognito When Supply Auth Code : How do I get Id and access tokens for testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am unable to successfully acquire an id token/access token from my AWS cognito user pool when I supply an auth code. I have written a shell script (see below), and receive `invalid_grant` back from the server.

I have encoded the base64 Authorization Basic header for `client_id:client_secret` generated with python as:

```py
import base64

encode='my_client_id_string:my_client_secret_string'
base64.b64encode(encode)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

curl --location --request POST 'https://<domain>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encode string client_id:client_secret>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<client_id from app settings' \
--data-urlencode 'code=<code received from redirect url to my localhost app endpoint>' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/my_redirect'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The problem was caused by an invalid client id. I had supplied a typo for the client id value!

Comment: When you say client_id from app settings is this the Cilent ID from the App Clients and Analytics page?